# How to update association table in Sequelize

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js

I have a product table and product image table.

```js
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
        const Product = sequelize.define("product", {
            id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
            name: { type: STRING },
            price: { type: STRING }
        }, {
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true,
        })
        Product.associate = function (models) {
            Product.hasMany(models.product_image, { as: 'images' });
        };
        return Product;
    
    }
```

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const ProductImages = sequelize.define("product_image", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        productId: { type: INTEGER},
        title: { type: STRING },
        url: { type: STRING }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })
    return ProductImages;

}
```

I could create a product and product image entires in a single statement by including the model in create method from the below payload

```json
{
    "name": "Product 1",
    "price": "10.00",
    "images": [
        {
            "title": "image 1",
            "url": "url 1 here"
        },
        {
            "title": "image 2",
            "url": "url 2 here"
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
db.product.create({
            name: body.name,
            price: body.price,
            images: body.images
        },
        {
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.product_images,
                    as: 'images'
                }
            ]
        }
        ).then(product => {\\ITS WORKED FINE. UPDATED BOTH TABLES WITH DETAILS
```

But I need to partially update the product and image details based on the below payload. I could update the product details. But image table is not updating

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "price": "55.00",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "image 11111111",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "url": "url 222222222 here"
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
let product = {}
product.id = body.id;
if(body.name) product.name = body.name
if(body.price) product.price = body.price
let productImages = []
body.images.forEach(image=>{
    let imageItem = {}; 
    imageItem.id = image.id;
    if(image.title) imageItem.title = image.title
    if(image.url) imageItem.url = image.url
    productImages.push(imageItem);
});
if(productImages.length > 0) product.images = productImages
console.log(product);//GOT CORRECT RESULT HERE WITH ONLY UPDATED DETAILS
db.product.update(product,
    {where: {id: body.id}},
    {
        include:[
                {
                    model: db.product_images,
                    as: 'images'
                }
            ]
    }
    ).then(rowsUpdated=> {
    
        //UPDATED ONLY THE PRODUCT TABLE
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use transactions to achieve this. So you will get complete control over the update event.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html
Refer unmanaged transactions

Comment: Please let me know if you have doubts